# Xamarin.Forms TCP SocketOptions AccessDenied

Tags: forms, xamarin, tcp

i'm new to Xamarin Forms and I'm not able to undestand why this line of code gives me an 'AccessDenied' Socket exception:

```
tcpAsyCl.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.NoDelay, 1);
```

If instead, I use:

```
tcpAsyCl.NoDelay = true;
```

the application seems to work properly!

Others SocketOption like:

```
tcpAsyCl.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, _timeout);
```

doesn't give me the same exception. My actual test configuration is this:

Win7; VS2019; Simulation with Tablet Android 8.0 API 26

Comment: Could you please post the full log of this error ?

Comment: The only thing i can see on the error essage box is this **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:** 'Access denied' and it is the same written in the output window. I'm trying to connect to a socket server at 10.0.2.2:8200. There is some place in which i can find a more detailed log?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the SocketOptionLevel.Socket should be SocketOptionLevel.Tcp as stated here: